# How to bootstrap residuals of two-way clustered standard errors

Tags: clustering, bootstrap

I'm doing a two stage model that I'm trying to bootstrap to get the covariance matrix of the second stage. My data is panel, with observations at the country quarter level. In the first stage I cluster by both country and quarter, get the fitted values of the dependent variable, then use this instrumented variable in my second stage regression. My question is how to account for the two-way clustering when bootstrapping the residuals. If it were one-way clustering I believe you could just do block clustering, e.g. if I just clustered by quarter, then I would create a new variable, call it epsilon_star, where I resample with replacement a residual from the same quarter as that observation. However I'm not sure how to extend this to two-way clustering. My current idea is to randomly sample one of the residuals from that country plus one of the residuals from that quarter minus a residual from the entire sample. I believe this would work, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts?